# Jquery Search and Replace w/ .contains

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do a search and replace with all instances of the same word, having not be case sensitive by using .contains () but it seems that it is not working and is case sensitive. Here is the code of what I have now:

```
<p>some text</p>
<p>Some Text</p>
<p>Some TEXT</p>


jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a, i, m) {
         return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
             .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
       };
       jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, i, m) {
         return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
             .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
       };


        $('p').filter(":contains('some text')").each(function(){
            $(this).text($(this).text().replace("some text", "replace with new text"));
        });
```

This only changes the first text, because of the same case
you can look at the example on js fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/ka82V/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue wasn't with the original matching, but with how you were replacing. Even if it *did* match, the replace did nothing because it's "some text" argument doesn't match the other case variants.

However, I don't think it's a good idea to override jQuery's `:contains` selector like this. Using a function-based filter is less code and leaves jQuery unaltered, as well.

See working example at: http://jsfiddle.net/Y6bhS/1/

```
$('p').filter(function() {
    return /some text/i.test( $(this).text() );
}).each(function(){
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/some text/i, "replace with new text"));
});
```

Comment: I do like this one and agree with you, that we should not override jQuery, that would be a bad idea. But have a question, what is the i.test for?

Comment: `.test` is a method on the `RegExp` object in JavaScript, that runs the regular expression against the argument (in this case `$(this).text()`) and returns true or false based on whether it matched. The `RegExp` object in this case is actually a literal (just as "some string" is a literal `String` object): `/some text/i`. The `i` part tells it to be case-insensitive.

Comment: @ChrissPratt I see thanks, I havent learned RegExp yet, I guess that is why I was having the trouble with the search and replace, but its working, thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

It's actually 'replace' that was case sensitive. Use a regex instead:

`text().replace(/some text/i, "replace with new text"));`

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/ka82V/1/

Comment: @KyleMacey  +1 thank you so much Kyle! I couldnt figure that out

Answer (score 2):

You contains looks fine. Try like below as the purpose of using `.filter` is to chain

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/ka82V/5/)

```
jQuery.expr[':'].containsCI = function(a, i, m) {
    return jQuery(a)
        .text()
        .toUpperCase()
        .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};

$('p').filter(":containsCI('some text')").text(function() {
    return $(this).text().replace(/some text/i, "replace with new text");
});
```

Comment: What if the OP doesn't want to replace ALL the text in the element?

Comment: @KyleMacey He can write the same replace code inside the return. Updated as that is how it was in his original post.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a, i, m) {
    return new RegExp(m[3], 'ig').test(jQuery(a).text());  // case insensitive replace
};
jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, i, m) {
    return new RegExp(m[3], 'ig').test(jQuery(a).text());  // case insensitive replace
};

$('p').filter(":contains('some text')").each(function() {
     $(this).text($(this).text().replace( new RegExp($(this).text(), 'i'),"replace with new text"));
});
```